# Linear Regression over Window in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, linear-regression

I want to perform a Linear Regression over a Window in PySpark. I have a timeseries and I want the slope of that timeseries for each person (identified by an ID) in a dataset looking 12 months back.

My idea was to do like this:

```
sliding_window = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-12, 0)
df=df.withColumn("date_integer", F.unix_timestamp(df['date']))
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['date_integer'], outputCol='features')
vector_df = assembler.transform(df)
lr = LinearRegression(featuresCol='features', labelCol='series')
df = df.withColumn('slope_window', lr.fit(vector_df).coefficients[0].over(sliding_window))
```

However, after 15 minutes of execution I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'over'
```

Any advice?

Comment: What were you expecting "over" to do there?  `lr.fit` returns a completed estimator, `coefficients[0]` returns the first coefficient as a number.  What can `over` do with that?

Comment: @TimRoberts My idea was to fit the regression over the window and return the coefficient of the slope to the column slope_window for each row in the dataframe.

Comment: I think you need to window your inputs, then feed that set to `fit`.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts - I tried to use the window over the assembler, but that didn't work. So I need to figure it out how to window my inputs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that only a small number of rows is required for each linear regression, you can switch  to [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) for the actual calculation and run these regressions in parallel using [Spark's udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html).

#### Generate some testdata

```python
from datetime import date, timedelta
import random
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

startdate = date.today() - timedelta(days=365)
data = [[id, startdate + timedelta(days=d), id * (d + random.random() - 0.5) ] for id in range(1,5) for d in range(1,10)]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'date', 'value']) \
    .withColumn("date_integer", F.unix_timestamp('date') / 60  / 60 / 24)
```

```
+---+----------+------------------+------------------+
| id|      date|             value|      date_integer|
+---+----------+------------------+------------------+
|  1|2022-03-31|0.6168826236941936|19081.916666666668|
|  1|2022-04-01|1.5357778308903614|19082.916666666668|
|  1|2022-04-08| 9.208155706805703|19089.916666666668|
|  2|2022-03-31|2.3609080691388877|19081.916666666668|
|  2|2022-04-08|17.476392355447565|19089.916666666668|
|  3|2022-03-31|2.4292967172497213|19081.916666666668|
[...]
```

#### Collect the input values for the linear regression in array columns

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

sliding_window = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-12,0)

df2 = df.withColumn('last_12_dates', F.collect_list('date_integer').over(sliding_window))\
  .withColumn('last_12_values', F.collect_list('value').over(sliding_window))
```

#### Define the udf that runs the linear regression

```python
@F.udf(returnType=T.DoubleType())
def linear_reg(dates, values):
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    x = np.reshape(dates, (-1,1))
    lr = LinearRegression().fit(x, values)
    return float(lr.coef_[0])
```

#### And finally execute the calculation

```python
df2.withColumn('slope_window', linear_reg(F.col('last_12_dates'), F.col('last_12_values'))) \
  .drop('date_integer', 'last_12_dates', 'last_12_values') \
  .show(truncate=False, n=50)
```

Result:

```
---+----------+------------------+------------------+
|id |date      |value             |slope_window      |
+---+----------+------------------+------------------+
|1  |2022-03-31|0.6168826236941936|0.0               |
|1  |2022-04-01|1.5357778308903614|0.9188952071961676|
|1  |2022-04-08|9.208155706805703 |1.1178376705639304|
|2  |2022-03-31|2.3609080691388877|0.0               |
|2  |2022-04-01|4.069062243789487 |1.7081541746505986|
|2  |2022-04-07|15.013921583339329|1.8849117914166331|
|2  |2022-04-08|17.476392355447565|1.8662925262252443|
|3  |2022-03-31|2.4292967172497213|0.0               |
|3  |2022-04-01|5.343956838751345 |2.914660121501623 |
|3  |2022-04-07|23.05250860814219 |2.938836071122241 |
|3  |2022-04-08|26.5399792695849  |2.942384338095864 |
|4  |2022-03-31|5.088327258258278 |0.0               |
|4  |2022-04-01|7.4632476763570015|2.3749204180987222|
|4  |2022-04-07|30.56238059275477 |3.900228891002952 |
|4  |2022-04-08|34.760905276327996|3.8133127278310197|
+---+----------+------------------+------------------+
```